# Transform solved code using loop and conditionals to list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have this code already solved using traditional methods:

```
edades = [10, 25, 49, 16, 60]
mayores_edad = []
for edad in edades:
    if edad >= 18:
        mayores_edad.append(1)
    else:
        mayores_edad.append(0)
print("Mayores de edad:", mayores_edad)
```

Now I want to do the same but using list comprehension.
I already did this:

```
mayores_edad_por_compresion = [x if (x >= 18) == 1 else 0 for x in edades]
print(mayores_edad_por_compresion)
```

The problem is that the result is this: `[10, 0, 0, 16, 0]`
and I need it to be this `[0, 1, 1, 0, 1]` like the traditional one.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, you want the value in the list to be `1` instead of `x` when the condition is true, so you should write

```
mayores_edad_por_comprehension = [1 if (x >= 18) else 0 for x in edades]
```

instead. Note that the comparison `==1` is not necessary and should be removed.

In addition, in this particular case, you can just convert the condition to an integer.

```
mayores_edad_por_comprehension = [int(x >= 18) for x in edades]
```

Whether this is better/clearer than the other approach is opinion-based, but it's good to know this alternative method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
mayores_edad_por_compresion = [1 if (x >= 18) == 1 else 0 for x in edades]
print(mayores_edad_por_compresion)
```

Explanation:
Just remove x with 1.
A list_comprehension looks like this

```
variable = [*value_if_condition_true* if (*conditional statement*) else *value_if_condition_false* for *variable_to_use_in_condition* in *your_list*]
```

Also, I wanna correct your coding techniques.
(x >= 18) == 1, this will work for you but try to prefer True/False if you wanna compare with boolean.
And,
int(x >= 18) is enough to run the if statement as you desired.

So, my final answer would be

```
mayores_edad_por_compresion = [1 if (x >= 18) else 0 for x in edades]
or
mayores_edad_por_compresion = [int (x >= 18) for x in edades]
```